# how to use ffmpeg on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to create video file from Jpeg and audio file.
I've compiled FFMpeg to android and I've got libffmpeg.so, and obj folder with ithers resources.

But how to use it?
What I need to do for use command like: "ffmpeg -i image.jpeg -i audio.mp3 out.avi"
Please help.

Comment: hey ALex did u solve it? m working on same sutff !! can u help?

Comment: hi, I want to compile ffmpeg with ndk in windows, can you guide me?

Answer (score 1):

From the [FFmpeg docs on images](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#image2-1):

> The following example shows how to use ffmpeg for creating a video from the images in the file sequence ‘img-001.jpeg’, ‘img-002.jpeg’, ..., assuming an input frame rate of 10 frames per second:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i 'img-%03d.jpeg' -r 10 out.mkv
> ```

To actually run it from Android, look at [the documentation for Runtime.exec()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I Know how to use ffmpeg from command line. I do not know how to use compiled ffmpeg librares on android.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include [JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/) wrapper methods that you can call from Java, that will in turn invoke the FFmpeg functions.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You may use JNI interface to call functions from a library, in your case ffmpeg library. Here is a basic tutorial of JNI: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

To put simply, JNI is the bridge between your Java code and C code.

In order to call ffmpeg as in command line from your Java code, You may include ffmpeg.c (and other needed files) into your jni interface (under jni directory) and compile it along with your other jni code, so that you may call ffmpeg's main function with arguments just like the command line.