# FFMPEG progress CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE ... ffmpeg: has text relocations

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to cut and merge the videos.I used FFMPEG. I have implemented this library https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java.

When i tested in android 8.0(Oreao) version. I got this issue " CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE ... ffmpeg: has text relocations". I found they opened issue for that...https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/141...is that any library that support all devices.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Most of the libraries are build for build version 7 which highest at that time when building

Answer (score 3):

This is a "known problem" and concerns x86 (not Arm). This problem is present in other libraries too which are based on FFMpeg. Here are some links where you can read about it:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4928
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191235

Comment: yes it is x86 problem not arm. its not working on emulator